# Laravel 5 - "laravel new" command

Tags: composer-php, laravel-5

Help guys in installing Laravel 5,

I'm using Windows 7 Home premium

I'm using the Git bash as my terminal

---

I run the command

```
composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"
```

And it successfully installed

But when I ran

```
laravel new blog
```

It shows the message below:

```
Crafting application...
'composer' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
Application ready! Build something amazing.
```

There's an error message "'composer' is not recognized....".
Why is this happening to me?
The composer command is working fine. :(

I've already added the path ";C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin" to my system variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! Tried to reinstall it at my office.

It seems that my internet connection at home blocks some websites and running this command

```
composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"
```

installed incomplete laravel installer.

Answer (score 1):

Run command install Laravel:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist
```

http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/installation

Comment: Yes, that command works with me. But I want to install laravel via Laravel Installer.